# Minecraft black screen AFTER updating lwjgl Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, minecraft

I am trying to download Minecraft and I get a black screen. I have already updated lwjgl to version 2.9.0. I have Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error log in the .minecraft folder? That will help identify the problem.  Are you using 32 bit or 64? Did you fallow the directions at http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL when updating lwjgl? if you are using a 64 bit computer, the lwjgl64.dll update will cause a black screen crash. This i a known issue.

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue until I realized I had updated the .jars but forgot to update the natives.  You might want to try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Please provide more details and expand your answer. How did you this?